# C# Interactive не поддерживает классы System.Index и System.Range из NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0

Не так давно обновил Visual Studio и поставил .NET Core 3.1. При создании проектов на данной платформе все нововведения C# 8.0, включая [Index](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.index?view=netcore-3.1) и [Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.index?view=netcore-3.1), работают нормально. Однако REPL-среда **C# Interactive** при попытке использовать эти классы выдает ошибки.

```
> 1..4
(1,1): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or imported
(1,1): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Index' is not defined or imported
(1,4): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Index' is not defined or imported
```

Однако другие фишки нового C# в интерактивной среде поддерживаются, например, объявления using, выражения switch и статические локальные функции.

Даже если подгрузить сборки данных классов через #r, ситуация не изменится.

> Сборки:
>   System.Runtime.dll, netstandard.dll

```
> #r "netstandard.dll"
. #r "System.Runtime.dll"
. 0..5
(3,1): error CS0518: <...>
```

Я предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что:

> Применяется к .NET Core 3.0 .NET Standard 2.1

Судя по значению свойства [`System.Environment.Version`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=netcore-3.0#System_Environment_Version) в **C# Interactive** используется .NET Framework 4.6+.

```
> Environment.Version
[4.0.30319.42000]
```

В то же время проекты на платформе .NET Core 3.x возвращают версию [3.1.0].

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать, что бы включить данные классы в интерактивную среду, либо перевести платформу на .NET Core последней версии?